# PyroCMS / Codeigniter Database error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pyrocms

My site was running fine, then out of no where I got this error

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 145

Table './sitename/default_ci_sessions' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

```
INSERT INTO `default_ci_sessions`
            (`user_data`,
             `session_id`,
             `ip_address`,
             `user_agent`,
             `last_activity`)
VALUES ('',
        'dad23c3ecc0460e7f37ec8c46c3f5c3f',
        'ipaddress',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36',
        1380030504)
```

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 998

Not sure what this is or how this can be fix.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your sessions table is marked as crashed und should be repaired.

Since those are "only" session data rows, you could delete the table and create a new one with the same name and the following design:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `default_ci_sessions` (
session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
user_data text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Structure is from [CodeIgniter Sessions doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html), which is also used in PyroCMS.

As to why it crashed: you would need to check the logs (Apache and/or MySQL) or check with your hoster/provider to get more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the PyroDatabase module that allow you to fix tables.
Here the download: https://github.com/adamfairholm/PyroDatabase